# Apple IAP - Array of return receipts when validation

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I try to update IAP such as new update from Apple site. It's here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW8
I previous version, when perform receipt validation, Apple Store only return status of current receipt. But now, in document, it's "In the JSON file, the value of this key is an array containing all in-app purchase receipts. In the ASN.1 file, there are multiple fields that all have type 17, each of which contains a single in-app purchase receipt."

I don't know why is array? (Such as Google play store, array means containing list of previous un-success transaction). I test in sandbox environment, buy only 1 item, but alway get return 3 receipts. Please tell me why and how to fix another receipt?